# Can using UnmanagedMemory.LPTStr instead of .ByValTStr result in memory corruption? Why?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, pinvoke, dllimport

We have a tree view in a windows forms app that shows files using the appropriate file icon using the following code.  My problem is that call to GetIcon() appears to corrupt my memory as I start getting various program crashes that I can't catch with a debugger after this call.
The program work when I change `managedType.LPTStr` to `managedType.ByValTStr`.  Is this a true fix or just masking the problem?

This code appeared to be working in our last product release and I can't see anything that has changed.  Using .NET 4.0.  I only see the issue in Release mode.

```
[DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
private static extern int  SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint dwFileAttributes, out SHFILEINFO psfi, uint cbfileInfo, SHGFI uFlags);

 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct SHFILEINFO
        {
            public SHFILEINFO(bool b)
            {
                hIcon=IntPtr.Zero;
                iIcon=0;
                dwAttributes=0;
                                szDisplayName = "";
                                szTypeName = "";
            }

            public IntPtr hIcon;
            public int iIcon;
            public uint dwAttributes;

                        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr, SizeConst = 260)]//works if .ByValTStr is used instead
                        public string szDisplayName;
                        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr, SizeConst = 80)]//works if .ByValTStr is used instead
                        public string szTypeName;
        };

 public static Icon GetIcon(string strPath, bool bSmall)
        {
            SHFILEINFO info = new SHFILEINFO(true);
            int cbFileInfo = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
            SHGFI flags;
            if (bSmall)
                flags = SHGFI.Icon|SHGFI.SmallIcon|SHGFI.UseFileAttributes;
            else
                flags = SHGFI.Icon|SHGFI.LargeIcon|SHGFI.UseFileAttributes;

            SHGetFileInfo(strPath, 256, out info,(uint)cbFileInfo, flags);
            return Icon.FromHandle(info.hIcon);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not a proper `LPStr` in the struct, so you can't try to marshal it as one and expect it to work:

```
typedef struct _SHFILEINFO {
  HICON hIcon;
  int   iIcon;
  DWORD dwAttributes;
  TCHAR szDisplayName[MAX_PATH];
  TCHAR szTypeName[80];
} SHFILEINFO;
```

- `LPTStr` you use when you've allocated a special block of memory just to hold this string (usually in a `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` or similar), then you've copied over your `string` to that unmanaged memory area.
- `ByValTStr` you use when you are literally passing in the actual string by value, not by reference to another area in memory.

The struct wants the proper value, not a pointer.

Comment: Thanks.  A colleague just came by and explained this just before I read you answer and I was about to answer it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but this helped me solve a crash that seemed to suddenly start popping up more often than not.  It appears that I started running into these issues after a .NET 4.5.2 update was rolled out via Windows Update.  `LPTStr` worked before the update and `ByValTStr` worked after.

Comment: If the question helped, just upvote the question instead of adding an answer :)